# "Grounds-up" as an adjective

Tags: phrase-usage

Is it correct to use "grounds-up" (intended meaning: "done from scratch", contracted from the expression "From the ground up"), as an adjective?

E.g.,

> "This is a grounds-up implementation of the back-end server."

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The correct term is "from the ground up" which calls to mind how a building is built.

See [from the ground up](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/from+the+ground+up) from TFD Online.

> **from the ground up**
>   starting with nothing *The company was built from the ground up by two very creative people*.

**edit**

OP refined his question in the comment, and here is my reply:

You could easily use the singular version as an adjective ("a from-the-ground-up implementation"). There would be a potential confusion, however, by merely calling something a "ground-up implementation" because that would invoke the idea of something that had been subjected to a grinding process. I'd advise using the whole phrase. But the point is never to use "ground**s** up".

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I was trying to avoid using "From the ground up" because I wanted to place it next to the noun (in this sentence it is important to strees that the implementation being talked about is new), and I wasn't sure if something like _"This is a from-the-ground-up implementation of..." would be correct.

Comment: @DanielArmengod: I focused on your misuse of the plural (grounds), but you could easily use the singular version as an adjective: "a from-the-ground-up implementation" ... there would be a potential confusion to merely calling something a "ground-up implementation" because that would invoke the idea of something that had been subjected to a grinding process."

Comment: I can't find any mention of ***bottom-up*** on this page. That and ***top-down*** are the standard "single-word" adjectival forms.

Comment: I think *bottom-up* conveys a different meaning from *from the ground up*. The former is more about spatial orientation or perspective, the latter about fundamentals and order.